# Dynamic default values for dynamically generated ng-model

Tags: angularjs

I am facing problem in populating default values for dynamically generated form fields in using angular. So, I have a login form that generates itself based on the attribtes returned by aREST interface. Therefore for my html page, I just have :

```
 <li ng-repeat="element in elements"> 
    <label>UserName</label>
    <input type="{{element.inputType}}" ng-model="{{element.fieldName[element]}}" required="required"/>
```

The default values are returned in an attribute called placehoder in elements object. following tag gives an idea of the task that I am trying to achieve

```
 <input type="{{element.inputType}}" ng-model="{{element.fieldName[element]}}" required="required" placeholder="{{element.placeholder}}"/>
```

Finally, when the user clicks submit , I need to post the default value of text field if it has not been changed.

Any help would be highly appreciated.
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for replying @nilsK, I am very new to javascript frameworks and Angular is the first one that I am having my hand on.
So in my R&D with it , I solved my issue by adding the two arrays of values i.e. FieldName and Placeholder to the scope object that I use to post data to my backend. I assign values to these arrays from the objects(placeholder and fieldName) that recieve from REST service as:

```
$scope.user={};
$scope.user.FieldNames=[];
$scope.user.FieldValues=[];

angular.forEach($scope.elements,function(value,index){
                       $scope.user.fieldValues[index] = $scope.elements[index].placeholder;
                       $scope.user.fieldNames[index] = $scope.elements[index].fieldName;




              })
```

and on the html form, I bind ng-model to the scope array of values that I want to display as defaults in text field.

```
<input type="{{element.inputType}}" ng-model="user.fieldValues[$index]" required="required" />
```

Therefore, the default values are posted if user does not change them and if there is a change, updated values are posted.
Any suggestions to improve this solution are most welcome.

Answer (score 0):

If you can add/use a library like [underscorejs](http://underscorejs.org/#defaults) or [lodash](http://lodash.com/docs#defaults), then you can use their _.defaults() :

```
var object = { 'name': 'barney' };
_.defaults(object, { 'name': 'fred', 'employer': 'slate' });
// → { 'name': 'barney', 'employer': 'slate' }
```

with angular only, you could add a directive to your form, that watches 'submit' and sets the default values for you.